# how does the compiler optimize this piece of code

Tags: c++, optimization

consider the following loop:

```
unsigned long x = 0;
for(unsigned long i = 2314543142; i > 0; i-- )
    x+=i;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

when I compile this normally it take roughly 6.5 seconds to execute this loop. But when I compile with -O3 optimization the loop gets executed in 10^-6 seconds. How is this possible? The compiler surely does not know how the closed form expression for x...

Comment: Have you tried doing assembly language output to see what code is generated?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any assembly

Comment: How do you time the loop?

Comment: But people here do... And that will be the key to answering your question.

Comment: I timed it with std::clock(). I know this is not the most precise, but since the gap is so massive I don't think this matters.

Comment: Compiler surely knows closed form expression here. It is not hard to compute.

Comment: "The compiler surely does not know how the closed form expression for x", hey, maybe it does! Or maybe it just simulates the whole loop at compile time and computes what x would be at the end. It'd only take a few extra seconds, tops.

Comment: This loop is just calculating the sum of an arithmetic progression, which has a very simple closed solution. Given a starting value `N`, the result is `N*(N+1)/2`.

Comment: ...wait. `i` is unsigned. `i >= 0` will always be true. You've got undefined behavior here. I'm surprised the loop ever ended at default optimization level.

Comment: That can be solved by changing the condition to `i > 0`, maybe he copied it wrong. It won't change the result, since adding `0` to `x` doesn't do anythiing.

Comment: yes I originally used >0. I corrected the question.

Comment: The sum of all integers from `1` to `n` is equal (mathematically) to `n*(n+1)/2`  (i.e. can be computed using an addition, a multiplication, and a division, rather than `n` additions).    One feature of a lot of compiler optimisers is that they recognise sequences of operations for which the result can be computed more simply (e.g. a closed form in this case) and either do the calculation at compile time or emit simple code to do it at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really have to know all about assembly to see that the complier determines the value of x at compile time, if compiling with optimization on.

I modified your code slightly to be able to use the online tool [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), changing the `std::cout << x << std::endl` to `extern unsigned long foo;` and `foo = x;`. Not really necessary but it makes the output cleaner.

Compiled with -O2:

```
test():
        movabs  rax, 2678554979246887653
        mov     QWORD PTR foo[rip], rax
        ret
```

Compiled with -O0:

```
test():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], -1980424154
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 0
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        add     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        sub     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 1
.L2:
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0
        setne   al
        test    al, al
        jne     .L3
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     QWORD PTR foo[rip], rax
        leave
        ret
```

Also: the first revision of your code with undefined behavior due to `i >= 0` just outputs:

```
test():
.L2:
        jmp     .L2
```

:-)

Comment: so it seems like the compiler is computing something at compile time. But I  cannot find the output value 2678554979246887653 anywhere...

Comment: @user3726947 sorry, I accidentally used `extern unsigned foo` instead of `extern unsigned long foo`. The updated answer shows the correct output value.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler determines that the value of x after the loop and uses that in the output statement.

Comment: That must be a rather slow compilation, relative to the length of the program.

Comment: Although I didn't measure it the compilation time seemed almost instant. Certainly not longer than the compilation time without -O3 optimization.